# .NET DllImport error EntryPointNotFoundException: Binding AWS-Encryption-SDK from C and C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, c, amazon-web-services, dllimport

I'm working on a .NET 5 project to bind the AWS-Encryption-SDK from C and C++ to C# using PInvoke, type marshalling, and the DllImportAttribute. When attempting to call this C++ function

```
aws_cryptosdk_keyring *Build(const Aws::String &generator_key_id, const Aws::Vector<Aws::String> &additional_key_ids = {}) const;
```

using

```
[DllImport("aws-encryption-sdk-cpp.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern aws_cryptosdk_keyring Build(string generator_key_id, string[] additional_key_ids = null);
```

I get this error

> System.EntryPointNotFoundException : Unable to find an entry point named 'Build' in DLL 'aws-encryption-sdk-cpp.dll'.

The dll signature for this function is

> ?Build@Builder@KmsKeyring@Cryptosdk@Aws@@QEBAPEAUaws_cryptosdk_keyring@@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBV?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@7@@Z

So far nothing that I have tried as the EntryPoint has been successful. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There's no such language as "C/C++", only the two very different and distinct languages C or C++. Please don't mix both together like that. Since you're attempting to call a C++ function, please remove the C tag (and all mentions of "C/C++").

Comment: You probably want an `extern "C"` around that function, to prevent name mangling.

Comment: C# is not going to magically know what to do with Aws::String and Aws::Vector. I mean can you even export C++ functions from a DLL like that? Generally to DllImort into C# you need a C interface. You could wrap your C++ making the AWS calls in a C function interface in various ways depending on the details.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @jwezorek's comment, C# does not know how to call C++ (class) functions, only C functions. There are several reasons why this is so, but I won't get into them here.

You need to create (in C++) a wrapper that converts each C++ call to a 'flattened' C call. For example:

```
extern "C" void *createClass() {
  return (void*) new myClass();
}

extern "C" void destroyClass(void* self) {
  delete (myClass*) self;
}

extern "C" int callFunction1(void* self, int x, int y) {
  return ((myClass*) self)->function1(x, y);
}
```

You'll need to write a function for each class function (plus the constructor and destructor). Then compile, linking it to that original C++ DLL's library. Then in C#, write a wrapper to call your flattened class:

```
public class myClass : IDisposable {
  [DllImport("myFlattenedDll", EntryPoint="createClass")]
  public static extern IntPtr createClass();
  [DllImport("myFlattenedDll", EntryPoint="destroyClass")]
  public static extern void destroyClass(IntPtr self);
  [DllImport("myFlattenedDll", EntryPoint="callFunction1")]
  public static extern int callFunction1(IntPtr self, int x, int y);

  private IntPtr self;

  public myClass() {
    self = createClass();
  }

  ~myClass() {
    Dispose();
  }

  public virtual void Dispose() {
    lock (this) {
      destroyClass(self);
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
  }

  public int callFunction1(int x, int y) {
    return callFunction1(self, x, y);
  }
}
```

You should also look into a tool called [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) that can automate a good deal of the wrapper coding for you.